# Как разделить текст на две строки в pascal?

Tags: pascalabc.net

Набросал программу в Паскале:

```
program prog1;
var A, B, C, D: integer;
begin
  read(A, B);
  C:= 2 * (A + B);
  D:= A * B;
  write('Периметр равен:', C);
  writeln('Площадь равна:', D);
end.
```

Выдает вот такую кашу:

> Периметр равен:xПлощадь равна:x

Как мне сделать так, что бы все по человечески было, в две строчки?

Comment: У вас же написана функция, которую надо использовать. Пробовали переставить их местами или почитать доки, чем отличаются `write` и `writeln`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
  writeln('Периметр равен:', C);
  writeln('Площадь равна:', D);
```